# ASP.NET Custom Control - Default Template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I know this is really picky, but can I have one template inside a user control:

```
<uc:MyUserControl runat="server" ID="test">
    <div><b>Test</b></div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="pH" />
</uc:MyUserControl>
```

Instead of what I have now which requires me to:

```
<uc:MyUserControl runat="server" ID="test">
    <Content>
        <div><b>Test</b></div>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="pH" />
    </Content>
</uc:MyUserControl>
```

Basically I want my control to have only one ITemplate inside of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content is an ITemplate property of the user control?  Try using this:

```
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.persistencemode.aspx

EDIT: Plus, you need to add the `[ParseChildren(True, "DEFAULTPROPERTY")]` attribute to the control as well.

Comment: I will accept your answer if you add that I needed [ParseChildren(True, "DEFAULTPROPERTY")] Attribute on the class...  The combination of the PersistenceModeAttribute on the Property and the ParseChildrenAttribute on the class.